# Use getContentResolver() and getWindow() in a non-activity class

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a class that extends AlertDialog.Builder and i would like to use getContentResolver() and getWindow() but eclipse give me this message: 
The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type MYCLASS
The method getWindow() is undefined for the type MYCLASS

How to solve this problem?

Comment: pass the activity context to the non activity class and use it there for `getContentResolver()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AlertDialog.Builder.getContentResolver()` and `AlertDialog.Builder.getWindow()`

Comment: The method getWindow() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder
Same message for getContextResolver()

Comment: The you must create these methods using `public static` in your AlertDialog.Builder class so you can use them in different classes. Do you have them as static?

Comment: Are there other solutions?

Comment: Other solutions are to put these classes in an interface, or simply declare these methods in each class. Another solution I in my opinion would be to create all objects used in those two methods as static. Then changing the method as static so you can use it. Please provide the code you tried so more solutions can be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`getWindow()` is a method of the dialog class, not of the dialog build.

Try like this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder bld= new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);AlertDialog alt= bld.show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = alt.getWindow().getAttributes();lp.dimAmount = 0.0F;
dlg.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always get that if you declare a context inside the method of the required non activity class exaample

```
  public class A 
  {
   ....
   .... 
   public PassInfo(Context context)
      {
        ContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ...........
        ...........
       }
   }
```